# Function Pointer Initialization in C/C++

Tags: c++, c, function-pointers, esp-idf

As I was going through a ESP IDF's documentation; I saw that a function pointer was initialized in a certain way that does not make sense to me.

```
typedef void *app_driver_handle_t;

app_driver_handle_t app_driver_light_init();
app_driver_handle_t app_driver_button_init();
```

Etc.

I thought that in order to initialize a function pointer, you must do it the following way:

```
app_driver_handle_t = app_driver_button_init();
```

Sorry for my beginner level questions.

It would do wonders if someone could explain this.

Thanks

Comment: Where is the function pointer? I see only a pointer to `void` mentioned, and there are no objects of that type in your code.

Comment: I think the reason this does not make sense to you is that what you see is not what is actually written. Since we can only see what is actually written, answers require guesses of what you see. It might be a good idea to go into your interpretation of this code in more detail. For example, what do you think `app_driver_handle_t` is? What about `app_driver_light_init`? I suspect one or both of these are off, and yet you asked your question with the implicit assumption that your interpretation of these is correct.

Comment: `app_driver_handle_t` is an alias for `void*` and not for a function pointer. Refer to a [good c++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) which are also available as PDFs for free.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's break down the code you're looking at.

```
typedef void *app_driver_handle_t;
```

This is *not* a function pointer. This is a `void` pointer, which means it can point to basically any values. And this is a *type*, not a value, so `app_driver_handle_t` does not actually contain any pointers at all; it's merely a name that's synonymous with `void*`.

```
app_driver_handle_t = app_driver_button_init();
```

Given the `typedef` above, this syntax is *never* valid. You're setting a type equal to what is presumably a function call. You can't assign to types. Full stop.

What you *can* do is declare variables and assign them the result of function calls.

```
app_driver_handle_t my_variable;
my_variable = app_driver_button_init();
```

or you can do it in one line.

```
app_driver_handle_t my_variable = app_driver_button_init();
```

Finally, these last two lines.

```
app_driver_handle_t app_driver_light_init();
app_driver_handle_t app_driver_button_init();
```

These are also not function pointers. These are function *prototypes*. They're a promise to the compiler, saying, "I will eventually define two functions called `app_driver_light_init` and `app_driver_button_init`. These two functions will take no arguments and will return a `void*`". There's still no function pointer happening here. The functions, when they're eventually defined, will return a `void*`, which, again, is not a function pointer but a pointer to `void`.

Answer (score 0):

This is effectively same as

```
void * app_driver_light_init();
void * app_driver_button_init();
```

These are not function pointers, they are functions that return `void*`.

A `typedef`'d fucntion pointer would look like this:

```
typedef void* (*app_driver_light_init)();
```